# Winforms Application keeps running after ShutDown, I can't debug why

Tags: vb.net, winforms, freeze

I have this VB.NET Winforms application that is making me sick... It works perfectly, but it keeps running on the background after shutdown. Form is closed, the event `My.MyApplication.ShutDown` is called, and yet it keeps running. If I try to pause and step-debug, VS IDE itself will freeze until I kill the process via Task Manager. Even calling `TASKKILL /F` won't make it stop sometimes.

The code is large and contains sensible information so I apologize for not posting it here. Anyway, I don't expect you guys to give me a definitive answer, rather I'd like to be told how could I properly investigate this, since Visual Studio isn't helping me there. Where should I start from?

Thank you very much

Comment: Document the installed anti-malware product.

Comment: @HansPassant it's *Trend Micro OfficeScan, Agent Version 12.0.4461 Service Pack 1*

Comment: Did you try the End statement, you can place it anywhere to force the entire application to stop running

Comment: @essanousy yes: `Application.Exit`, `Environment.Exit`, `End`... When step-debugging, those were the last lines run before IDE went zombie and process stuck among Task Manager's background processes.

Comment: Are there any FormClosing eventhandlers or OnFormClosing overrides that set `e.Cancel=True`?  That coupled with hiding the Form would simulate that problem, but does not prevent Task Manager from closing the application.

Comment: Usually you need to dump the process, and then analyze the hang dump for conclusion. You might also use Process Monitor to see what is the remaining thread of your process and check if its call stack is meaningful. Too broad to discuss such troubleshooting over Stack Overflow. Open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com would be a typical way to get the assistance you need.

Comment: Check Event Viewer. Sometimes there is a clue in there.

Comment: Maybe a simple `Me.End` might terminate everything?